# How can I convert a long date with time to a different format in VBA?

Tags: vba

I have data for a date that looks like this: "2015-02-11T19:41:50-08:00"

I would like to know if there is already a function that exists in VBA which can convert the above data to the format of something like "02/11/2015 11:41 AM PST"

I attempted the following code playing around with the format function but was unable to get VBA to recognize the format as a date:

```
testdate = "2015-02-12T22:57:05-08:00"  

newdate = Format(testdate, "mm/dd/yyyy hh/nn/ss AM/PM")  

Debug.Print newdate
```

The output was still "2015-02-12T22:57:05-08:00"

Thanks for the help.

Edit:

I was able to resolve the problem by taking your suggestions to use the mid() function since the dates are in fixed format. I decided to keep the military time in the final version.

Here is my code for anyone curious:

```
Function convertDate(orderdate)
'takes the date formatted as 2015-02-06T08:26:00-08:00
'and converts it to mm/dd/yyyy hh/nn/ss UTC format

'2015-02-06T08:26:00-08:00

orderyear = Mid(orderdate, 1, 4)
ordermonth = Mid(orderdate, 6, 2)
orderday = Mid(orderdate, 9, 2)
orderhour = Mid(orderdate, 12, 2)
orderminute = Mid(orderdate, 15, 2)
ordersecond = Mid(orderdate, 18, 2)


newdate = ordermonth & "/" & orderday & "/" & orderyear
newtime = orderhour & ":" & orderminute & ":" & ordersecond

'Debug.Print newdate
convertDate = newdate & " " & newtime & " UTC"

End Function
```

Comment: Please format your code accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Because your input isn't a true date none of Excel or VBA's date methods will work with it. Your best bet is to break the string down into parts, work with them individually, and then join it all back up again - for example:

```
testdate = "2015-02-12T22:57:05-08:00"

'// The letter T is redundant, so let's split the string here into an array:
dateArr = Split(testdate, "T")

    '// Part 1 of the array can be easily converted with CDate() and Format()
    dateArr(0) = Format(CDate(dateArr(0)), "mm/dd/yyyy")

    '// Part 2 of the array will need to be broken down further:
    dateArr(1) = Format(TimeValue(Split(dateArr(1), "-")(0)) - _
        TimeSerial(Left(Split(dateArr(1), "-")(1), 2), _
            Right(Split(dateArr(1), "-")(1), 2), 0), "hh:mm:ss")

'// The above line does the following:
'//     1) Split the second part of the array again, using the "-" as the delimiter
'//     2) Convert the first part of this (22:57:05) to a time using TimeValue()
'//     3) Convert the second part (08:00) to hours & minutes using TimeSerial()
'//     4) Minus the latter from the former (which can only be done if both are a valid time)
'//     5) Wrap all that into a Format() method to show "hh:mm:ss" instead of a Double.


    '// Join the two parts back together and add "PST" on the end.
    newdate = Join(dateArr, " ") & " PST"

Debug.Print newdate

'// Output will display "02/12/2015 14:57:05 PST"
```

---

**N.B.** *I have chosen not to include "AM" or "PM" because your time is in 24hr format anyway so I don't see the relevance...*

Answer (score 1):

It's not converting because of the "T" and because of the tacked on time range at the end. You can ditch the "T" and truncate off the trailing range and it will convert.

```
Public Sub Example()
    Const testValue As String = "2015-02-12T22:57:05-08:00"
    Dim dateValue As Date
    Dim stringValue As String
    Dim subVal As Date
    Dim hyphenPos As Long
    stringValue = testValue
    Mid(stringValue, 11&, 1&) = " "
    hyphenPos = InStrRev(stringValue, "-")
    subVal = Mid$(stringValue, hyphenPos + 1&)
    dateValue = CDate(Left$(stringValue, hyphenPos - 1&)) - subVal
End Sub
```

Comment: The time section is a time, minus the "tacked on" hours/minutes value - this just ignores the latter part which would produce an incorrect value.

Comment: Mmm that was not immediately clear to me, but code is updated accordingly.

Comment: It's not entirely clear from the OP's question, I'll take back the vote.

Comment: It appears I can't "take back" a vote - so now you have an upvote instead - enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ideas:

1. The sample date you have `2015-02-12T22:57:05-08:00` is not a real date (I think)
2. I think the following will give you the closest format to what you are looking for (you will need to define the range.`Range.NumberFormat = "[$-409]h:mm:ss AM/PM"`

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is concating "PST" to a date datatype formatted to your needs.

```
Sub DebugPrintDate()
Dim testdate As Date: testdate = Now
newdate = Format(testdate, "mmm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM") & " PST"
Debug.Print newdate
End Sub
```

Ouput:

[image]

Never mind the "*févr*". My system locale is France.

If you want to define a particular date, make sure to wrap the date in two #s.

Example:

```
  Dim someDateAndTime As Date = #8/13/2002 12:14 PM#
```